# MySQL on PHP need 2 reloads to update the values

Tags: php, html

I made a message deleter button, but I need 2 reloads to appear the changes...
(The rest of the code work, so it's normal that I don't show you the rest of the code...)

```
            <?php while($r = $replies->fetch()) { ?>
        <div class="message" id="<?= $r['id'] ?>">
            <div class="profile">
                <img class="avatar" src="members/avatars/<?php if(empty(get_avatar($r['id_author']))) { echo "default.png"; } else { echo get_avatar($r['id_author']); } ?>" width="150" height="150">
                <h3 style="text-align: center;"><?= get_username($r['id_author']) ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="date">
                    <?= date('d F Y - g:iA', strtotime($r['date_hour_post'])) ?>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($r['content']) ?>
                <form method="POST"><button name="delete<?= $r['id'] ?>">Test</button></form>
                <?php
                    $test = "delete".$r['id'];

                    if(isset($_POST[$test])) { 
                        $delete = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM f_messages WHERE id = ?');
                        $delete->execute(array($r['id']));
                        $success = "Your message was successfully removed !";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <?php } ?>
```

UPDATE:

I added the deleting code at the top of my php code, and it's working, thanks to Ray Andison

By the way thanks to keidakida too; he helped me to find a solution to my value problem. (And I think he don't know that)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make a message deleter button for a forum

Comment: Can't understand the demo GIF properly. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I click on the button, we don't see it but the page reloads, and after that, the message is always here, and if I reload (CTRL + R) the message dissapear

Comment: always delete or update records before the list block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form doesn't contain any data (the id to be deleted) or action (page to submit data to)?

```
<form method="POST" action="thispage.php">
<input id="test" name="test" type="hidden" value="<?= $r['id'] ?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

UPDATED:

```
<?
  if(isset($_POST[id])) { 
    $delete = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM f_messages WHERE id = ?');
    $delete->execute(array($_POST[id]));
    $success = "Your message was successfully removed !";
  }

while($r = $replies->fetch()){
echo '
<div class="message" id="'.$r[id].'">
  <div class="profile">
    <img class="avatar" src="members/avatars/';

    if(empty(get_avatar($r[id_author]))){
      echo "default.png";
    }else{
      echo get_avatar($r[id_author]);
    }

echo '
    " width="150" height="150">
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">
      '.get_username($r[id_author]).'
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="date">
    '.date('d F Y - g:iA', strtotime($r[date_hour_post])).'
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    '.htmlspecialchars_decode($r[content]).'

    <form method="POST" action="thispage.php">
      <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$r[id].'">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>';
}
?>
```

This is how I would code this, you need to change the action="thispage.php" to be the name of itself so it posts to itself, replace with the actual name of your php file

Comment: updated with the way I would write the code, also please note in your example the sql to delete comes after fetching and displaying the data

Comment: This work, but I always need to reload a second time to see the change

Comment: The first section deletes the msg by id..the second displays all fetched msgs, the only reason I can think of without seeing your entire code would be that the page is getting these results before you delete the message...if there is more code above this move the delete section of code to the very top of the php file before anything else, that way when your script gets the msgs, it is already deleted

Comment: Yes, that's it !! Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome.. as mentioned, an improved way to send and receive form data is through ajax, at the moment you have php on server building and displaying the front end.. with ajax you send requests from the front end to another php file on the server (known as an api, is just a php file that gets data and sends it back) which returns information back and updates the page without refreshing anything (works async (at the same time the user is still using the page(in the background)))..highly recommend looking up ajax and json and learning how this is done, can also use jquery which has methods forthis

Answer (score 1):

It is because the delete PHP code is at the bottom. Actions such as delete should be at the top of the HTML or while loops before presenting the data. SO try this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["delete"])) { 
        $delete = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM f_messages WHERE id = ?');
        $delete->execute(array($_POST['delete']));
        $success = "Your message was successfully removed !";
    }

    while($r = $replies->fetch()) { ?>
        <div class="message" id="<?= $r['id'] ?>">
            <div class="profile">
                <img class="avatar" src="members/avatars/<?php if(empty(get_avatar($r['id_author']))) { echo "default.png"; } else { echo get_avatar($r['id_author']); } ?>" width="150" height="150">
                <h3 style="text-align: center;"><?= get_username($r['id_author']) ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="date">
                    <?= date('d F Y - g:iA', strtotime($r['date_hour_post'])) ?>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($r['content']) ?>
                <form method="POST">
                    <button type="button" name="delete" value="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">Test</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    <?php 
    }
?>
```

But you can do the same functionality without any page reload. Check [AJAX PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

Comment: Like the first answer, this work but I always need to reload a second time to see the change

Comment: Then one way would be to automatically make user refresh it. Using PHP's `header("Location: currentpage.php")` this will do the work though but I prefer AJAX

Comment: I'd include the `type` attribute in `button` tag since different browsers may use different default types for button element. in that case `<button type="submit"></button>` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yeah submit is the default type for a button. Explicitly mentioning it would be good too

Comment: I don't really know Ajax... Do you have a little example for what I want please ?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer just a minute

Answer (score 0):

Since it would be better and easier with AJAX, this is how it goes:

main.php

```
<?php
while ($r = $replies->fetch()) { ?>
    <div class="message" id="<?= $r['id'] ?>">
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['content']) ?>
        <button onclick="delete('<?php echo $r['id']; ?>')">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <br>
<?php } ?>
<script>
    function delete(id) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert("Delete successfully");
                location.reload();
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "delete.php", true);
        // Mandatory for simple POST request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // Send id you want to delete
        xmlhttp.send("id=" + id);
    }
</script>
```

And make another PHP file name is delete.php like this:

```
<?php

include 'YOUR_DB_Connect.php';

if(isset($_POST["delete"])) { 
    $delete = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM f_messages WHERE id = ?');
    $delete->execute(array($_POST['delete']));
}

?>
```

Comment: Not much point in using ajax if you just use location.reload() in the xml response. The whole purpose of using ajax is to async update data and view without the need for page refreshing? Basically this just slows down the operation with an additional server request then reloads the page anyway

Comment: It's not working, but that's weird, I saw this error on my Chrome console :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'delete'
It's maybe better to use the first solution...